# Pointer to memory location stored in uint64_t

Tags: c++, pointers

If I have the address of a memory location stored in a variable, i.e. `uint64_t` for 8 byte pointers on 64-bit systems, can I use the value stored in the `uint64_t` to create a new pointer pointing to the memory location that it holds?

```
struct Node { .. };
Node* node = new Node(5);
uint64_t addr = (uint64_t)static_cast<void*>(&node); // 8 byte pointer
```

For example the address of node is `0x7fff76bb4880`, `addr` stores `140735185373312` (the dec representation), and I want a new pointer `Node* new_ptr = (Node*)0x7fff76bb4880`.

I realize this will be platform specific.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The standard guarantees that a pointer can be converted to a "large enough" integer type and back again resulting in the same pointer value. Specifically, C++11 5.2.10 Reinterpret cast [expr.reinterpret.cast]/4:

> A pointer can be explicitly converted to any integral type large enough to hold it. The mapping function is implementation-defined.

and 5:

> A value of integral type or enumeration type can be explicitly converted to a pointer. A pointer converted to an integer of sufficient size (if any such exists on the implementation) and back to the same pointer type will have its original value; mappings between pointers and integers are otherwise  implementation-defined.

The types `intptr_t` and `uintptr_t` from `<cstdint>` - if supported - are guaranteed to be large enough to store any object pointer type. Typically they are used - even when you know that `uint64_t` is the size of a pointer on your platform - because they make it clear that you intend to convert between pointers and integers.

I'll leave as an exercise for the reader to prove that the C casts are equivalent to performing `reinterpret_cast`.

TLDR: The standard guarantees that this program will never fail the assertion:

```
auto pointer_as_int = reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(&foo);
auto int_as_pointer = reinterpret_cast<decltype(&foo)>(pointer_as_int);
assert(&foo == int_as_pointer);
```